# Unable to retrieve geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, localhost

I am trying to run a Javascript code to retrieve a device's geolocation. When I try to run the code from the localhost (127.0.0.1) the code runs as expected, opening a pop up to ask the user to enable location services. However, when I try to host this code or access it using the local IP address (192.168.x.y), the code fails with an error

Any ideas as to why it works for localhost and not otherwise.

Here's the JS Code

```
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer this without posting the code that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: It may be due to chrome browser setting.I had similar issue i tried using IE

Comment: @pvg The code works fine when run from 127.0.0.1 so I assumed the issue isn't with the code. Little presumptuous. Nevertheless, I have mentioned the link from which I've taken the code

Comment: Can you include an [MCVE] in your question? There's no need to add 'EDIT', just make your question such that other people can reproduce the behaviour you are having a problem with.

Comment: @soorapadman It does work with IE but doesn't with Chrome or Safari. What kind of setting do you think is interfering?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: @HellsGuardian pvg already shared the link

Comment: You can also make your life a lot easier by actually handling the returned error instead of just throwing it away. If you'd taken the `PositionError` param in `error` and looked at its `message` property you'd have got a useful hint along the lines of 'Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service'

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Chrome require secure protocols for some features. Fore example a page must be served up httpS for it to be able to obtain the user's geolocation.

The restriction is relaxed for localhost to enable dev/debugging.